# How did tokenOfOwnerByIndex get used without ERC721Enumerable?

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

- @openzeppelin/contracts v4.4.1
- solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.11;

I have a contract that compiles and works fine on test net, and uses tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index)

```
contract NFT is ERC721, IERC721Receiver, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++) {
        tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_wallet, i);
    }
   ...
}
```

I later read that tokenOfOwnerByIndex is in ERC721Enumerable, but I cannot compile when I try to use it.

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol" not found
import  "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
```

Is the contract that compiles and doesn't import ERC721Enumerable, safe just to use?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the node_modules files, the npm @openzepplin/contracts ERC721 contract imports ERC721Enumerable.

When The contract is in Remix IDE, an error is thrown saying tokenOfOwnerByIndex is not found.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721Enumerable, IERC721Receiver,  Ownable, ReentrancyGuard{
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think this is what is happening here. Truffle does not modify your contracts and does not inject anything into your inheritance hierarchy. Are you sure you don't have `tokenOfOwnerByIndex()` defined somewhere? Maybe you could provide a more complete snippet because from what you're showing in the question it looks like it should not compile.

Comment: @cameel Looking at the node_modules files, the npm @openzepplin/contracts ERC721 contract imports ERC721Enumerable. I edited the answer.